# How to calculate a TCP packet checksum using Python?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, scapy

I'm using Scapy (the below code) to capture the IP/TCP packets on network:

```
sniff(iface='ens33', prn=call_back, filter="ip and dst host 10.0.0.12", store=0)

def call_back(packet):
    ip_packet = packet['IP']
    tcp_packet = ip_packet['TCP']
```

When I got 'ip_packet', I need to change its source address to another one, and send it out.

How can I re-calculate its checksum in IP header and TCP header?

Answer (score 0):

Scapy will do that for you, provided you remove the existing value:

```
def call_back(packet):
    del packet[IP].chksum, packet[TCP].chksum
    packet[IP].src = "1.2.3.4"
    sendp(packet)
```

If `packet` does not include an `Ether()` layer and starts directly with the `IP()` layer, replace `sendp()` by `send()`.